# Passagem de objetos por referencia c++

Tags: c++, objetos

Fala galera, estou tentando aprender um pouco de C++ e tenho uma duvida com relação a passagem de objetos para uma class e manipulação do mesmo dentro desta.
Consigo fazer isso em C#, mas estou tentando em c++ sem ter muito sucesso.

Exemplo: c#

```
class Folha
{

    public void Marcar()
    {
       ...
    }

}

class Papel 
{

    Folha f;

    public Papel(Folha folha_)
    {
        f = folha_;
    }

    public void MarcarFolha()
    {
        f.Marcar();
    }
}

void main()
{

    Folha folha = new Folha();
    Papel papel = new Papel(folha);
    papel.MarcarFolha(); 

}
```

É possível este tipo de abordagem em c++??? Se sim, como implementar?

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer o mesmo em C++ é comum de passar um ponteiro para o objeto no construtor da classe.

O mesmo exemplo poderia ser codificado assim:

```
class Folha
{

public:

    void Marcar(){
        cout<<"Marcar de folha";
    }
}; /*<--- ; é necessário em c++*/

class Papel
{
    Folha *f; //guardado como ponteiro

public:

    Papel(Folha *folha_){ //recebe ponteiro
        f = folha_;
    }

    void MarcarFolha()
    {
        f->Marcar(); //acede com -> por ser ponteiro
    }
};

int main()
{
    Folha folha; //cria objeto de forma estatica
    Papel papel(&folha); //passa o seu endereço
    papel.MarcarFolha(); //escreve Marcar de folha

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/z5gaXa)

Repare atentamente nas diferenças. Apenas foi escrita uma vez a palavra `public` e tudo o que está dali para baixo é publico. O `Folha` foi guardado como ponteiro na classe `Papel`.

Naturalmente também podia fazer o `main` com `new` parecido ao que tem em C#, assim:

```
void main()
{
    Folha *folha = new Folha(); //ponteiro
    Papel *papel = new Papel(folha); //ponteiro também
    papel->MarcarFolha(); 
}
```

Mas isto obriga-lhe depois a liberar os objetos com `delete` quando não precisar deles, o que acaba por se tornar mais difícil de gerir. Por este motivo deve dar preferência à primeira forma que apresentei

**Utilizando passagem por referência do C++**

```
class Folha
{

public:

    void Marcar(){
        cout<<"Marcar de folha";
    }
}; 

class Papel
{
    Folha f; //guardado sem ser como ponteiro

public:

    Papel(Folha &folha_){ //recebe a referência
        f = folha_;
    }

    void MarcarFolha()
    {
        f.Marcar(); //acede agora com . porque não é ponteiro
    }
};

int main()
{
    Folha folha; //cria objeto de forma estática
    Papel papel(folha); //passa normalmente
    papel.MarcarFolha();

    return 0;
}
```

[Exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/APSUBe)

Internamente a referencia, é tratada como um ponteiro no método onde foi utilizada. Note no entanto que neste último caso a folha recebida no construtor será copiada para o campo da classe chamado `f`, o que irá ser diferente da `folha` que tinha no `main`. O mesmo não acontece nos exemplos anteriores, e suspeito que não era este o comportamento que pretendia.

Comment: Beleza, funcionou. Mas assim estamos usando ponteiros. Dá para fazer o mesmo usando "passagem por referência". Eu tento fazer e sempre da erro acho que não dá só para substituir os operadores "*" por "&", não é?

Comment: @guidogd Já editei a resposta para contemplar esse cenário. Veja se responde ao que estava a perguntar e/ou se ficou com mais alguma questão